# When object stored in useContext updates DOM does not rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am writing an application that basically is a game. The information about the game is stored in a context provider that wraps the entire application. I have written prototype methods for the game object and call them in the react app but the changes do not appear on the page.

```
const onDeckEl = useRef(null) 
useEffect(() => {
    let onDeck = round.getOnDeck()
    onDeckEl.current = onDeck
    console.log(onDeckEl)
}, [round])
```

I can see in the dev tools that the values of the arrays in the round object are changing when I want but the console.log is never fired. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason the `console.log` is not firing is because the `round` variable isn't changing. The code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Effect!');
}, [round])
```

wont fire unless the `round` variable changes.

Comment: The round variable is an object that holds a few arrays. The contents of those arrays are changing and I can see that in the dev tools, is there a way to force a rerender when an array changes?

Comment: does the round object comes form the context API?. If the object is actually changing and the useEffect is not triggered, It might be because the component actually is not rendering